# .NET: Interface Problem VB.net Getter Only Interface

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Why does an **interface** override a **class** definition and violate class encapsulation?  I have included two samples below, one in **C#** and one in **VB.net**?

### VB.net

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim testInterface As ITest = New TestMe
        Console.WriteLine(testInterface.Testable) ''// Prints False
        testInterface.Testable = True             ''// Access to Private!!!
        Console.WriteLine(testInterface.Testable) ''// Prints True

        Dim testClass As TestMe = New TestMe
        Console.WriteLine(testClass.Testable)     ''// Prints False
        ''//testClass.Testable = True             ''// Compile Error
        Console.WriteLine(testClass.Testable)     ''// Prints False
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class TestMe : Implements ITest
    Private m_testable As Boolean = False
    Public Property Testable As Boolean Implements ITest.Testable
        Get
            Return m_testable
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            m_testable = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Interface ITest

    Property Testable As Boolean

End Interface
```

### C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace InterfaceCSTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ITest testInterface = new TestMe();
            Console.WriteLine(testInterface.Testable);
            testInterface.Testable = true;
            Console.WriteLine(testInterface.Testable);

            TestMe testClass = new TestMe();
            Console.WriteLine(testClass.Testable);
            //testClass.Testable = true;
            Console.WriteLine(testClass.Testable);
        }
    }

    class TestMe : ITest
    {
        private bool m_testable = false;
        public bool Testable
        {
            get
            {
                return m_testable;
            }
            private set
            {
                m_testable = value;
            }
        }
    }

    interface ITest
    {
        bool Testable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### More Specifically

How do I implement a **interface** in **VB.net** that will allow for a **private setter**. For example in C# I can declare:

```
class TestMe : ITest
{
    private bool m_testable = false;
    public bool Testable
    {
        get
        {
            return m_testable;
        }
        private set //No Compile Error here!
        {
            m_testable = value;
        }
    }
}

interface ITest
{
    bool Testable { get; }
}
```

However, if I declare an **interface** property as **readonly** in **VB.net** I cannot create a setter. If I create a VB.net **interface** as just a plain old **property** then interface declarations will violate my **encapsulation**.

```
Public Class TestMe : Implements ITest
    Private m_testable As Boolean = False
    Public ReadOnly Property Testable As Boolean Implements ITest.Testable
        Get
            Return m_testable
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As Boolean) ''//Compile Error
            m_testable = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Interface ITest

    ReadOnly Property Testable As Boolean

End Interface
```

So my question is, how do I define a **getter only Interface in VB.net with proper encapsulation**?

I figured the first example would have been the best method. However, it appears as if interface definitions overrule class definitions. So I tried to create a **getter only (Readonly) property** like in **C#** but it does not work for **VB.net**. Maybe this is just a limitation of the language?

### Update

As per Hans Passant's comment I have submitted a feature request found : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635591/create-a-readonly-interface-that-allows-private-setters-c-to-vb-net-conversion

Please vote for it if you would like the same compatibility feature as well!

Comment: You can't, it is not permitted syntax.  Post a feature request at connect.microsoft.com, the team is receptive to any requests that make both languages feature comparable.  For now, you'll have to use a private method to set the backing field.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Thank you. Feature Request can be found here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635591/create-a-readonly-interface-that-allows-private-setters-c-to-vb-net-conversion

Comment: You need to removed the ReadOnly. Period.

Comment: @AMissico: Why? Now I have just given access to my private variable through Interface instances. I think Hans Passant's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @snmcdonald: You cannot specify ReadOnly with Set. It is a compiler error. You cannot even do this in C#.

Comment: @AMissico: "A property without a set accessor is considered read-only." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(v=vs.80).aspx So **yes** you can specify a read-only property with a set in C# (see my question "No Compile Error here!").

Comment: @snmcdonald. Yes, but in VB.NET you must provide the ReadOnly keyword if you do not provide the Set. Just like Hans Passant says, "It is not permitted syntax."

Comment: I upvoted the feature request, good ask.  One downvote, I didn't realize that that connect was stackoverflowian.  First time I've seen that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it in VB.NET:

```
Public Interface ITest
    ReadOnly Property Testable As Boolean
End Interface

Public Class Test
    Implements ITest

    ' Note: Here I am NOT implementing the interface. '
    Private _testable As Boolean
    Public Property Testable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _testable
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _testable = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' This is where I define a read-only property to satisfy the interface '
    ' (from the perspective of the VB compiler). '
    ' Notice this is a lot like explicit interface implementation in C#. '
    Private ReadOnly Property TestableExplicit() As Boolean Implements ITest.Testable
        Get
            Return Testable
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. I always wondered why VB.net had to explicitly state its implementation. That makes sense.

Comment: @user295190 It's not so much "had to" as "gets to", in my opinion.  You get a lot more flexibility in VB than in C# when it comes to naming and visibility of interface implementations.

Answer (score 1):

When an interface calls for a read-only property, your implementation should omit the setter.  Properties declared 'Read-Only' cannot have a 'Set'.

Comment: I am aware (Readonly Property Testable as Boolean) != ( bool Testable { get; } ). I would like to know how to achieve something similar in VB.net.

Comment: One more note - It's not so much of a language limitation as it is a syntactic difference.  The ReadOnly keyword is VB.NET's answer to the private setter.

Answer (score 0):

Dan answered your second question, let me answer your first one:

> Why does an interface override a class definition and violate class encapsulation?

This is not specific to properties. Consider the following (simpler) example, which shows the same behavior as your example:

```
Interface I
    Sub DoSomething()
End Interface
```

What does this mean? It means that if you have an object `i` of type `I`, you can always call `i.DoSomething()` publicly.

```
Public Class C
    Implements I
    Private Sub DoSomething() Implements I.DoSomething
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

By using `Implements I.DoSomething`, you specify that *if* an object of class `C` is accessed through interface `I`, calling `I.DoSomething` will execute your private method `C.DoSomething` (which happens to share the same name, but that's just a coincidence). This is not a violation of encapsulation: By using `Implements ...`, *you* specify that you *want* this method to be accessible via this (public) interface method. So, basically, you can think of the `Implements` keyword as providing a second means of access to this method (or property, in your example), which is independent of the access modifiers of the "main" means of access.

Thus, `DirectCast(myC, I).DoSomething()` will work (since it accesses the interface method, which happens to "call" your private method), but `myC.DoSomething()` will not compile when used outside of `C`.

The same thing happens in your example: Specifying `Property Testable As Boolean` in your interface guarantees that `obj.Testable = ...` can be called (publicly) on every `obj` of type `ITest`.